# How to remove parentheses and apostrophe mark in output list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to remove the parentheses and apostrophe mark from an output Excel file that has one list (EX: ('INTCAS199', 'INTCAS253')). I would like it to be INTCAS199, INTCAS253 instead.

Here's my code so far:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

lists_combos = "combos_lists.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(lists_combos)

list_1 = list(df['List 1'].dropna())
list_2 = list(df['List 2'].dropna())

pairs=[(x,y) for x in list_1 for y in list_2]
print(pairs)

outputDf=pd.DataFrame(data=[pairs]).transpose()
outputDf.columns = ['Paired']
outputDf.to_csv('combos_done.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Include a sample combos_list.csv. The first 6 lines should be fine. We should be able to copy it and make it part of a verified solution.

Comment: You want the output CSV to be a single column?

Comment: It sounds like these values are strings and you want to concatenate them into a single string. So, `pairs=[" ".join((x,y)) for x in list_1 for y in list_2]`. The transpose now makes the dataframe a single row with many columns and then you try to give it a single column name. If you would just post a sample CSV it would be much simpler to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

> (EX: ('INTCAS199', 'INTCAS253')). I would like it to be INTCAS199, INTCAS253 instead.

The code below does the 'cleanup' you are looking for. The function to use is `replace`

```
input_str = '''('INTCAS199', 'INTCAS253')'''
output_str = input_str.replace('(', '').replace('\'', '').replace(')', '')
print(output_str)
```

output

```
INTCAS199, INTCAS253
```

Comment: ugly hack. Shouldn't OP just join these pairs into the string he wants at the beginning?

Comment: @tdelaney I agree it is not a "very nice" solution...